# Test that array.sample doesn't give consecutive equivalent results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How would I go about testing the following helper method?

```
module HypotheticalHelper
  def next(array)
    array.sample
  end
end
```

I have this:

```
helper.next([1,2]).should_not == helper.next([1,2])
```

Is there a better technique than repeating this a statistically significant number of times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What behavior are you trying to test? That you get random elements from the array? If so, then just run the test until the same call returns an element that doesn't match the last run.

How would this be used? If you want random access to an array, why not simply `array.shuffle!` and then iterate the array?

`Array#sample` *can* give consecutive equivalent results; it's expected that it will. If you want to never have the same results concurrently, then you'll have to maintain state and loop until you get a result that wasn't the last result, or you'll want to use something like my shuffle suggestion (which will never give repeating results).

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't have to be Array#sample - I may change the implementation of the method later on. I want to test that it will never give consecutive results, when the method has an element of randomness.

Comment: I know how to ensure this in the code but unsure how to test it. Perhaps this is an example of something which is not worth testing?